# How to specify Makefile target building order without put any physical dependencies?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have been working on a C++ project that links to a .so(dynamic library) file.
Let's assume that I have a target PROG which needs to link to a.so, and a.so is also built by me, specified in the following Makefile.

```
PROG_SRCS = prog.cpp
PROG_OBJS = $(PROG_SRCS: %.cpp:%.o)

all: PROG
PROG: $(PROG_OBJS) liba.so
    $(LINK.cpp) -o $@ $(PROG_OBJS) -la

LIBA_SRCS = liba/a.cpp
LIBA_OBJS = $(LIBA_SRCS: %.cpp:%.o)

liba.so: $(LIBA_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cpp) -shared -Wl.-soname,$@ -o $@ $^
```

I have used auto-dependency-generation to get the .cpp files get their own dependency on
the .h files. And prog.cpp includes a.h.

But by this way, once I change a.cpp, liba.so would be remake, then PROG would be 
remake(relink), which is not what I want. I just change the implementation of liba.so,
but not any interface definitions. PROG should just remake after I change a.h.

I want to make that a.so should be built before PROG is built, but the changes of a.so would not incur the building of PROG.

The following Makefile is the method I figured out, but with a slightly side-effect
(generate a temporary file).

```
ORDER = /tmp/.ORDER

all: PROG
PROG: $(PROG_OBJS) $(ORDER)
    $(LINK.cpp) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@ $(PROG_OBJS) -la

$(ORDER): liba.so
    test -e $@ || touch $@
```

In this way, every time liba.so gets remake, $(ORDER) gets remake too. But it only touch
the file if it doesn't exist.

Is there any way to specify this kind of dependency without any side-effect, e.g. creating a tmp file.

Comment: If you want to just built the library you could use `make liba.so`

Comment: Hi, DrYap. I want to build PROG and detect whether liba.so needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: You said that the there is a dependency file so that `prog.cpp` depends upon `a.h`.  So PROG will be rebuilt if the interface changes. But why does `PROG` depend upon `liba.so` ?  I would expect `all` to depend upon `liba.so` instead.

Comment: Hi, Morris. As you said, `all` can depend on `PROG` and `liba.so` at the same time. But you must specify the building order between them, so that `liba.so` will be built before building `PROG`. And this is my question.

Comment: Doesn't the order of entries on the `all: liba.so PROG` line define the build order?  I thought it did.  Certainly seems to with simple things of mine.

Comment: For `make -j1`, which is default option, this would work. But if you run it by `make -j2`, it would cause problem. If `liba.so`'s building time is longer than `PROG`'s, it is not guaranteed that `PROG` use the new `liba.so`. The problem is `PROG` is not explicitly depended on `liba.so`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to rely on non-portable aspects of GNU make, you can use order-only prerequisites [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) for this.  That's the only way to do it other than the stamp file method you've already discovered.