# how to specify link order in makefile so don't get undef for one class that relies on the other

Tags: c++, linux, macos, gcc, makefile

My classes are very interdependent, and I am getting an undefined symbol when I build for gcc 4.2(mac) but not gcc4.4 (linux). What I think is happening is that the build order is coming into play for mac but not linux.  I'm trying to figure out how to change my makefile to do this correctly.  I've been looking at [order only prerequesites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458999/how-to-specify-makefile-target-building-order-without-put-any-physical-dependenc), but I'm not sure how to do this for my makefile.

This is my makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .cpp

DEP_DIR = ../dep

CC = g++

OS := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    #set LIB_DIR
    LIB_DIR1=darwin64_gcc42/lib
    LIB_DIR2=darwin64_gcc44/lib
else
    LIB_DIR=linux64_gcc44/lib
endif

INCDIRS = -I. -I../include \
        -I$(DEP_DIR)/s/include \
        -I$(DEP_DIR)/t/include

ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    C++FLAGS = -c -fPIC -g -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall
    #C++FLAGS = -c -fPIC -O2 -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall
else
    C++FLAGS = -c -fPIC -g -O2 -DLINUX -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall
    #C++FLAGS = -c -fPIC -O2 -DLINUX -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall
endif

ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
        LDFLAGS = -m64 -pthread -ldl -dynamiclib -L../$(LIB_DIR1)/debug \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/slx/$(LIB_DIR1) \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/tbb/$(LIB_DIR2)/debug
else
    LDFLAGS = -m64 -pthread -ldl -shared -L../$(LIB_DIR)/debug \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/s/$(LIB_DIR) \
        -L$(DEP_DIR)/t/$(LIB_DIR)/debug
endif

LDLIBS = -lu_debug -ls_debug -lt_debug -ltmalloc_debug
#LDLIBS = -lu -ls -lt -ltmalloc

all: UMetaPlugin UDataPlugin UForPlugin UFacPlugin UTransPlugin UPlugin

UPlugin: UPlugin.o
    $(CC) UPlugin.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

UDataPlugin: UDataPlugin.o
    $(CC) UDataPlugin.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

UForPlugin: UForPlugin.o
    $(CC) UForPlugin.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

UFacPlugin: UFacPlugin.o
    $(CC) UFacPlugin.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

UMetaPlugin: UMetaPlugin.o
    $(CC) UMetPlugin.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

UTransPlugin: UTransPlugin.o
    $(CC) UTransPlugin.o $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS)


.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(C++FLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o all
```

What appears to be happening, is that UDataPlugin.cpp instantiates UMetaPlugin, and since the link is separate, UDataPlugin gets an undefined symbol for UMetaPlugin.  How do I postpone the link so that UDataPlugin doesn't try to link without UMetaPlugin?

This seems to work at the command line for mac, so this seems to reinforce the issue is order dependent with the link:

```
 g++ -fPIC -g -O2 -D_DEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -Wall -I. -I../include -I../dependencies/s/include -I../dependencies/t/include UMetaPlugin.cpp UDataPlugin.cpp UForPlugin.cpp UFacPlugin.cpp UMetaPlugin.cpp UPlugin.cpp -ldl -m64 -pthread -dynamiclib -L../darwin64_gcc42/lib/debug -L../dependencies/s/darwin64_gcc42/lib -L../dependencies/t/darwin64_gcc44/lib/debug -lu_debug -ls_debug -lt_debug -ltmalloc_debug
```

I wound up with this so I wouldn't have to suppress undefs, so it did it all in one step instead of trying to link separately:
appn = ex

SRCS=UMetaPlugin.cpp UDataPlugin.cpp UForPlugin.cpp UFacPlugin.cpp UMTransPlugin.cpp UPlugin.cpp

objects=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(appn)

$(appn): $(objects)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(objects) $(LDLIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(C++FLAGS) $(INCDIRS) $< -o $@

Comment: Ido not understand how this could work. Either each od `U*Plugin.cpp` sources defines `main`, in which case, the command line for mac that you are providing should complain about multiple definitions of main, or only one of the source files defines `main`, in which case all the other `U%Plugin` targets should complain about undefined reference to `main'. Can you edit your post to clarify what I am missing? Can you also add the output with the command line and error message?

Comment: there is no main for building this directory. This is intended as a dll/plugin for use by other programs. I find that if I comment out the code that instantiates the line with the undef, it has an undef elsewhere that uses the UMetaPlugin.  If I comment out that line, it will complain about the next interdependent one I'm sure.  Right now I think it's  stopping with the first undef it finds.

Comment: Have you tried `g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress `?

Comment: When I tried adding -undefined suppress to my LDFLAGS, and do a make after a clean, gcc says ld: can't use -undefined warning or suppress with -twolevel_namespace

Comment: try adding `-flat_namespace`

Comment: that worked with -undefined suppress.  Hopefully my team doesn't mind suppressing undefs.  Thanks for the help!